# Error when creating dynamic terraform rule for alb listener rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, listener, rules, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created several application load balancer listeners using the following block:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "apps_listener_forward" {
  for_each          = toset(var.apps_listener_ports)
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.apps_alb.arn
  port              = each.value
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06"
  certificate_arn   = var.ssl_cert

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      dynamic "target_group" {
        for_each = aws_lb_target_group.apps_tg
        content {
          arn = target_group.value["arn"]
        }
      }
      stickiness {
        enabled  = true
        duration = 86400
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is a listener rule I am trying to apply for all the listeners created above:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "apps_https_listener_rule" {
  for_each     = toset(var.apps_listener_ports)
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.apps_listener_forward[each.value].arn

  action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      dynamic "target_group" {
        for_each = aws_lb_target_group.apps_tg
        content {
          arn = target_group.value["arn"]
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = var.images
    content {
      path_pattern {
        values = condition.value.paths
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is how the target groups are being created. These target groups are to be forwarded to from the listeners with the rules applied:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "apps_tg" {
  for_each    = var.images
  name        = each.key
  port        = each.value.port
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.apps_vpc.id

  health_check {
    interval            = 130
    timeout             = 120
    healthy_threshold   = 10
    unhealthy_threshold = 10
  }

  stickiness {
    type            = "lb_cookie"
    cookie_duration = 86400
  }
}
```

Below are the variables being used:

```
variable "app_listener_ports" {
 type = list(string)
  default = [
    80, 443, 22, 7999, 8999
  ]
}

variable "images" {
  type = map(object({
    app_port = number
    paths = set(string)
  }))
  {
    "app-one" = {
      app_port = 3000
      paths = [
        "/appOne",
        "/appOne/*"
      ]
    }
    "app-two" = {
      app_port = 4000
      paths = [
        "/appTwo",
        "/appTwo/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

When I attempt to `terraform plan` I get a proposed plan with no errors. However when doing a `terraform apply` I'm getting an error. Below is the proposed plan output and the error when applying. Note, the plan output is actually longer due to number of listeners, but I only included the plan for one listener. All plan output is similar for each listener.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_lb_listener_rule.apps_https_listener_rule["443"] will be created
  + resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "apps_https_listener_rule" {
      + arn          = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + listener_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:listener/app/apps-dev/d32b94bab736a1eb/bb88fe24635339c0"
      + priority     = (known after apply)
      + tags_all     = (known after apply)

      + action {
          + order = (known after apply)
          + type  = "forward"

          + forward {

              + target_group {
                  + arn    = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/app-one/b4d5890e7e1396d8"
                  + weight = 1
                }
              + target_group {
                  + arn    = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:targetgroup/app-two/793ca533433c81fa"
                  + weight = 1
                }
            }
        }

      + condition {

          + path_pattern {
              + values = [
                  + "/appOne",
                  + "/appOne/*",
                ]
            }
        }
      + condition {

          + path_pattern {
              + values = [
                  + "/appTwo/",
                  + "/appTwo/*",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Error

```
 Error: Error creating LB Listener Rule: ValidationError: A rule can only have one 'path-
pattern' condition
│       status code: 400, request id: 81229cab-c7ca-4706-8339-df8f56b6a5d9
│
│   with aws_lb_listener_rule.apps_https_listener_rule["443"],
│   on alb.tf line 60, in resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "apps_https_listener_rule":
│   60: resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "apps_https_listener_rule" {
```

I believe this error is coming because I have multiple target groups that need to be routed to according to the path. I've been having some issues getting these rules to apply.

Any advice on how to apply these successfully would be helpful.

Comment: btw, I have also updated this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857402/create-multiple-target-groups-and-listeners-using-for-each/74857679#74857679

But seems like you already got it.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Michaels, I think it is better (or now is the time) to make abstractions and not use dynamic blocks anymore with the condition.

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "app1_https_listener_rule" {
  for_each     = toset(var.listner_ports)
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.app_listener_forward[each.value].arn

  action {
    type = "forward"
    forward {
      dynamic "target_group" {
        for_each = aws_lb_target_group.app_tg
        content {
          arn = target_group.value["arn"]
        }
      }
      stickiness {
        enabled  = true
        duration = 86400
      }
    }
  }
  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = [
        "/appOne",
        "/appOne/*" ## can also use variables if you prefer !!
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and similarly, you can add `resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "app2_https_listener_rule" {[...]}` this will simplify the variable `images`(*paths can be removed*) and also make the code more readable which will result in easy Maintainance in my point of view.

Hope it helps.